# regex expression to find words with 0

Tags: regex

Please provide a regex expression to find words with 0 like 'A0lytics', 'Alter0tive Medicine'.
But, it should not match words like 'Enterprise 2.0'

Comment: If you're wondering why you're getting negative votes, "please provide" is not a question, it's a work request.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no question here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this list of words: ["A0lytics", "0tics", "Alter0tive Medicine", "Enterprise 2.0"]

- `\w+0\w+` will capture "A0lytics" and "Alter0tive" (not "Alter0tive Medicine")
- `^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0]+(?: +[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0]+)*$` will match "A0lytics" and "Alter0tive Medicine"
- `(?<!\.)([a-zA-Z]*)0([a-zA-Z]*)` will match "A0lytics", "0tics" and "Alter0tive Medicine" (if you can use the negative lookbehind).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0]+(?: +[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0]+)*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gJ5ugU/2

Answer (score 0):

```
\w+0\w+
```

is it useful?
You can test online regular expressions with [this](https://regexr.com/).